# finding the computable function in s-m-n theorem.

Tags: computer-science, computability

in s-m-n theory if $\phi_e^{(m+n)}(x,y)$ is a computable function with index $e$ then there is a total comutable (m+1)-ary function $s_n^m(e,x)$ such that:$$\phi_e^{(m+n)}(x,y)=\phi_{s_n^m(e,x)}^n(y)$$

here $m$ is the size of tuple $x$ and n is the size of tuple $y$ and $e$ is the code of program $p_e$ that computes $\phi^{(m+n)}(x,y)$.

i wanted to know if is there any way to find the formula for $s_1^1(e,x)$ function $(m=n=1)$.

is there any way to calculate it using $e$ and $x$?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes: $s_n^m$ itself is a computable function! That's the real content of the theorem.
So you can just "run it" to calculate the value.
Any (reasonable) proof of the s-m-n theorem should show you a way to compute it.

What the value is exactly is not too important however:
it depends on the way you arithmetize computable functions (how you code computable functions for your "universal machine" $\phi^n_e(\dots)$).

(I would have posted this as a comment, but I don't have the reputation for it. If the above is not clear, let us know what source you are using. Then we can help you figure out what it should be for your particular formalization of computable functions.)

Comment: thanks for the explanation. my reference is cutland-an introduction to recursive function theory. its about URM or unlimited register machines.

Comment: @nerd001 I see. I'm not familiar with the book, but looking at the proof of the s-m-n theorem in it, $s^1_1(e,x)$ basically takes the program that is coded by $e$ and then adds some instructions in front of it.

How is this possible? Well, by theorem 1.3 and 1.4, we know how programs are coded as a number. If you look closely at those proofs, you will see how you can modify $e$ to "add these instructions at the front". It involves quite some calculations to do this for complicated $e$. But the important part is to convince yourself that it is a computable process to do this modification.